# How to add chevron to Collapse in table in reactstrap

Tags: reactstrap

I have a Table and I have Collapse component in each row. I want to add chevron to it and when I clicked it I want content to be appeared and chevron changes its shape. How can I do that in table ?

Ps: Is it possible to do that without defining state?

Here is an example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-uncontrolled-collapse-2qgsf6?file=index.js,index.html

Comment: Since the accordion controls hide/show, it would be difficult to propagate this state back up to the `App`. I would check ReactStrap's documentation on callback/listeners/events when clicking on the header.

Comment: I tried some css tricks but couldn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a controlled `Collapse` instead of an `UncontrolledCollapse`.

Also, your data should be in an array, and be mapped inside the `render()` function.

Finally, I would also avoid using a clunky `<table>` element to structure your content. Go with a FlexBox or Gird layout.

**Note:** If `this.state.toggleStates[index]` is `true`, this means that the `.AccordianItem` is expanded.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Card, CardBody, Collapse } from 'reactstrap';

import './style.css';

const rows = [
  {
    title: 'Request Headers:',
    body: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Nesciunt magni, voluptas debitis similique porro a
    molestias consequuntur earum odio officiis natus, amet
    hic, iste sed dignissimos esse fuga! Minus, alias.`,
  },
  {
    title: 'Request Headers:',
    body: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Nesciunt magni, voluptas debitis similique porro a
    molestias consequuntur earum odio officiis natus, amet
    hic, iste sed dignissimos esse fuga! Minus, alias.`,
  },
];

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      toggleStates: Array.from(rows, () => false),
    };
  }

  toggleIndex(index) {
    const toggleStates = [...this.state.toggleStates];
    toggleStates[index] = !toggleStates[index]; // toggle the state
    this.setState({ toggleStates });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="Accordion">
          {rows.map(({ title, body }, index) => (
            <div className="AccordionItem">
              <div
                className="AccordionItemHeader"
                onClick={() => this.toggleIndex(index)}
              >
                <box-icon
                  name={
                    this.state.toggleStates[index]
                      ? 'chevron-down'
                      : 'chevron-right'
                  }
                ></box-icon>
                <b>{title}</b>
              </div>
              <div className="AccordionItemContent">
                <Collapse isOpen={this.state.toggleStates[index]}>
                  <Card>
                    <CardBody>{body}</CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Collapse>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
html,
body,
#root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.App {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 400px;
}

.Accordion {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.AccordionItem {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.AccordionItemHeader {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: #ddd;
}

.AccordionItemContent {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Here is the modified StackBlitz:

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-uncontrolled-collapse-pzq9af?file=style.css